# sliding div with URL content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a two column page where links clicked on the left will cause content from another URL (on the same domain) to slide horizontally to the right.

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RZpbK/) is a good example of what I am aiming for.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to load external content using this script. jQuery's `.load(url);` seems like the ideal way to achieve this, but I cannot get it to work with the jQuery shown in the fiddle above.

Does anyone know if this can be done, or alternatively if there is a better method to achieving the same effect?

Code from fiddle below.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
            animIn = function () {
                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            };

        if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: -$this.width()
                }, 500, animIn);
            });
        } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            animIn();
        }
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
#left, #right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: As seen in the docs, [**load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to specify a callback function which is executed once `load()` has completed. You add the `load()` call to the `$('a.panel').click()` event. `load()` will then load the content into your target `div` and in your callback you start the slide effect on the `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `animIn` function to load content:

```
animIn = function () {
    $target.load(URL, function() {
        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    });
};
```

Just replace `URL` with the actual URL.

Update: this is [the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/RZpbK/862/):

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
        animIn = function () {
            $target.load('/echo/html/', {delay:0.5,html:$target.text()}, function() {
                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            });
        };

    if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: -$this.width()
            }, 500, animIn);
        });
    } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        animIn();
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like the right direction, however I am unsure how to have a different URL load in the right column depending on which link was clicked. 
For example: clicking "Target 1" would load "target1.htm" in the right column, whereas clicking "Target 2" would load target2.htm instead.

Comment: Well, you have `$target` already. You can do `$target.load($target+'.html', function() {...` or something similar.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm still very much a beginner with jQuery. I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchrislawson/N43Qt/12/) however no matter what I try, the links still open in the browser as opposed to being loaded into the sliding div.

Comment: In your updated Fiddle, please could you explain how and where the URL's should be placed for each link in the left column? I'm very grateful for your assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're requesting content that is not already on the page, you're best bet is to add a serverside component (php, ruby, etc) that you can request the second piece of content and have the server send it back.

ie

```
$("#target1).click(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "your-script.php", 
data: {target: "send-target-one-please"}, 
success: function(){
//append your second piece of content here
}
}); 
});
```

Then in your script (php):

```
function someFunction(){
//get your content here
$myContent = file_get_contents('../path/to/my/file'); 
echo json_encode($myContent); 
}
```

Obviously this is pseudo code but its the general idea